# urequests micropython problem (multiple POST requests to google forms)

Tags: http, python-requests, esp8266, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to send data to Google Forms directly (without and external service like IFTTT) using an esp8266 with micropython. I've already used IFTTT but at this point is not useful for me, i need a sampling rate of more or equal to 100 Hz and as you know this exceeds the IFTTT's usage limit. I've tried making a RAM buffer, but i got a error saying that the buffer exceded the RAM size (4 MB) so that's why im trying to do directly.

After trying some time i got it partially. I say "partially" because i have to do a random get-request after the post-request; i don't know why it works, but it works (in this way i can send data to Google Forms every second approximately, or maybe less). I guess the problem is that the esp8266 can't close the connection with Google Forms and it gets stuck when it tries to do a new post-request, if this were the problem, i don't know how to fix it in another way, any suggestions? The complete code is here:

```
ssid = 'my_network'
password = 'my_password'

import urequests

def do_connect():
    import network
    sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        sta_if.active(True)
        sta_if.connect(ssid, password)
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            pass
    print('network config:', sta_if.ifconfig())


def main():
    do_connect()
    print ("CONNECTED")
    url = 'url_of_my_google_form'
    form_data = 'entry.61639300=example'   #have to change the entry
    user_agent = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    while True:
        response = urequests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)
        print ("DATA HAVE BEEN SENT")
        response.close
        print("TRYING TO SEND ANOTHER ONE...")
    response = urequests.get("http://micropython.org/ks/test.html")  #<------ RANDOM URL, I DON'T KNOW WHY THIS CODE WORKS CORRECTLY IN THIS WAY
    print("RANDOM GET:")
        print(response.text)
        response.close


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you for your time guys. Also i've tried with this code before but it DOESN'T WORK. Without the random get-request, it gets stuck after one or two times of posting:

```
while True:
        response = urequests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)
        print ("DATA HAVE BEEN SENT")
        response.close
        print("TRYING TO SEND ANOTHER ONE...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `response.close()` (with brackets)?.. ,

Without brackets you access a (non existing) **property** `close` of the object `response` instead of calling the **method** `close()`, and do not really close the connection. This could lead to memory overflow.

Comment: Can you please be more clear? The question asked for a lot(which is completely acceptable) and you gave one sentence for an answer? Please edit your answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
I've added an explanation for my answer.
Thanks.